# Google Maps v3 Direction Icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On Google Maps when displaying driving directions there are direction icons located on the left (roundabout, left arrow, right arrow etc), I've searched through the documentation and can't find a way to display the icons on a module that I'm creating, has anyone found a way to display them on the direction pane.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not documented. The icons are part of the sprite image at http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/dir/tt3.png. In order to implement icons, you will need to parse the text of that stage of the route and select the correct sprite image to display.

Comment: Hi Andrew, do you mean I have to look for certain keywords within the text and display the icons. When localising, this would become another issue as well as all the functionality that Google maps already offers ie. hover over etc.

This will be tricky if thats the case, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, although it's probably the only solution at the moment, it's not a practical one for me, localisation etc would be a massive issue to cater for. I'll update if I find a better one. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the "maneuver" field in `routes[i].legs[j].steps[k].maneuver` to display these icons.

If you have a look at the [setPanel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel) tutorial, you can see that it's using the maneuver field to set the corresponding icon in the directions panel. You can check that the icon for each step is set by the CSS class ".adp-{maneuver}".

Here's a list of maneuvers that I found within the CSS file that this example is using:

- ferry
- ferry-train
- fork-left
- fork-right
- keep-left
- keep-right
- merge
- ramp-left
- ramp-right
- roundabout-left
- roundabout-right
- straight
- turn-left
- turn-right
- turn-sharp-left
- turn-sharp-right
- turn-slight-left
- turn-slight-right
- uturn-left
- uturn-right

It seems like these maneuvers are not affected by localization, so it shouldn't be an issue.